# ErrorException preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array. Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form input field that accepts an array of values:

`<input name="subjects_studied[]" type="text" placeholder="" size="30" class="form-styles" >`

In my routes.php script I have a closure like thus:

```
Route::post('apply', function() {

    $v = ApplicationForm::validate(Input::all());

    if ( $v->passes() ) {

        $data = array(

                 //  'subjects_studied' =>  Input::get('subjects_studied'), 
                   'subjects_studied' => (is_array(Input::get('subjects_studied'))) ? 
                                            implode(" , " , Input::get('subjects_studied')) : 
                                            Input::get('subjects_studied'),

                   );

          ApplicationForm::create($data);
    }
}
```

I've tried both configs and they both give me an error:

`ErrorException
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array.`

As a last throw of the dice, I tried:

```
$subjects_studied = Input::get('subjects_studied');
            foreach($subjects_studied as &$studied){
                $_subjects[] = $studied;
            }

            $x = implode($_subjects);

$data = array('subjects_studied' => $x,)
```

Could you help me insert an array of value(s) from a HTML form into a MySQL database using laravel?

Comment: How do you mean an array of values? Is this into a single field?

Comment: Yes, a single field. A user is able to increment the subjects he or she studies - by way of a jQuery add another subject button. This would duplicate the `<input name="subjects_studied[]" type="text" placeholder="" size="30" class="form-styles" >` element.

Comment: It seems to work now, must have been a problem with another one of my form elements to raise that error.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you need a loop to get all this values and save to database.

What I would do is:

```
$subjects_studied = Input::get('subjects_studied');
for ($i=0; $i < count($subjects_studied) ; $i++) { 
    $subject = new ApplicationForm;
    $subject->subjects_studied = $subjects_studied[$i]
    $subject->save(); 
}
```

or try with foreach

```
foreach ($subjects_studied as $key => $value) {
    $subject = new ApplicationForm;
    $subject->subjects_studied = $value
    $subject->save();
}
```

good luck